# No wifi on IdeaPad 3 17ABA7 (Realtek b852)

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, realtek

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 3 17ABA7 with a fresh Debian Bullseye installation. Unfortunately WLAN doesn't work out of the box.

lspci lists the following network device:

```
2:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
```

Which wifi driver do I need for Linux and where to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IdeaPad 3 17ABA7 seems to come with the Realtek chip RTL8852BE. It is supported by the following driver: https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.

Note the different installation instructions for rtl8852be depending on the Kernel version of your Linux system. For kernel < 5.18 the *master* branch should be used, for kernel >= 5.18 the *dev* branch should be used instead. If you have kernel > 6.0 the instructions suggest to use this driver instead: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw8852be.